# Why file.exists(tempfile()) return FALSE?

Tags: r

A simple question today for which I can't find a solution. Why `file.exists()` returns FALSE? I have plenty of space on my HD, so I do not understand what is going on.

```r
file.exists(tempfile())
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The first thing written in `help('tempfile')` is *tempfile returns a vector of character strings which can be used as names for temporary files.* It doesn't actually create the file, just a unique name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that return value because `tempfile()` does not itself create a file. Instead, as described in `?tempfile`:

> 'tempfile' returns a vector of character strings which can be used as
>   names for temporary files.

To see this yourself, try the following

```
## `f` is just a character string
f <- tempfile()
f
## [1] "C:\\tmp\\RtmpUdx1MU\\file26fc52b52d77"
class(f)
## [1] "character"
file.exists(f)
## [1] FALSE

## Writing something to the path given by `f` is what creates the file
cat("Hello", file = f)
file.exists(f)
## [1] TRUE
```